# How to check an ajax nonce in PHP

Tags: ajax, attachments, nonce, media-modal, backbone

I'm modifying the media modal adding a new menu item to add external attachments to the media library. From the JS code I'm calling a PHP function that touches the database and accepts three parameters (url, post id and nonce). My question is, how can I check the nonce from the PHP code? Another question, is sending a nonce really necessary in this case?

**JS:**

```
wp.media.controller.Custom = wp.media.controller.State.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.props = new Backbone.Model({ url: '' });
    },

    customAction: function(){
        wp.media.post( 'add-attachment', {
            url:     this.props.get( 'url' ),
            post_id: wp.media.view.settings.post.id,
            nonce:   wp.media.view.settings.post.nonce
        });
    }

});
```

**PHP:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add-attachment', 'add_attachment' );
function add_attachment() {
    $url = trim($_POST['url']);
    $post_ID = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    CHECK NONCE HERE!

    if (!current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_ID ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    $attachment = array( ...data... );
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_post( $attachment );
    if( ! is_int($attachment_id) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    if ( ! $attachment_js = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment_id ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $attachment_js );

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 4.1.1, the nonce is defined in `wp-includes/media.php`, line `2883`:

```
$settings['post'] = array(
    'id' => $post->ID,
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'update-post_' . $post->ID ),
);
```

So to verify the nonce:

```
wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, "update-post_$post_ID" );
```